# Flutter listen to change in String?

Tags: flutter, stream, onchange

How to listen to changes in a string

```
factory SomeService() {
  return SomeService._(
    aGlobalStateVarChanged: GlobalState.aGlobalStateVar.onChange,
  )
}
```

where `aGlobalStateVarChanged` is of type `Stream<String>`

But the above doesn't work

```
The getter 'onChange' isn't defined for the type 'String'.
```

Thank you

Comment: what is `GlobalState.aGlobalStateVar`?

Comment: @pskink GlobalState is a class, and aGlobalStateVar is a String in that class

Comment: if `aGlobalStateVar` is a string then error is right: `String` class does not have `onChange` method, where did you get that `onChange` from?

Comment: @pskink but how do I listen for changes in a string?

Comment: use `ValueNotifier<String>` for example